# How determine if user has enabled Authenticator

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-identity

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 3.0 Application which uses the Identity Framework to authenticate users. Datasource is an MS SQL Server database.

As two factor authentication, the default MS Authenticator is configured and working.

Actually, I have some users who have enabled the Authenticator and some (most) who have not. 
Those who have not, I want to show an additional menu item. Most of the menu items are build, based on the roles and it works fine.

Is this possible with the framework or do I have to query the users table by myself?

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager


@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    //...

    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Profile</a>

    //...

    @if (!_2faEnabled) //How to determine _2faEnabled?
    {
        <li><a href="~/Profile/Manage/EnableAuthenticator">Enable 2FA</a></li>
    }

    ///...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the current user by using the `UserManager` as:

```cs
var user = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

then get the `TwoFactorEnabled` value from the `user` object.

---

**Note:** if the `Enable 2FA` is in the main menu e.g.: Home | Projects | Tasks | Enable 2FA | ..etc. then IMO this would be a problem, because you would hit the database every-time the user navigates through your website. sooo you might consider storing the value of `user.TwoFactorEnabled` somewhere after getting it the first time from the DB.

Whereas if the `Enable 2FA` is inside a specific page e.g: `Manage 2FA` and inside it you get `the current user` and then check for the `TwoFactorEnabled` would not be that bad (because users would not access this page that often).

Comment: As the variable name says "TwoFactorEnabled". so this value will be true if the phone or email enabled while authenticator isnt

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using "[GetValidTwoFactorProvidersAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getvalidtwofactorprovidersasync?view=aspnetcore-3.0)"

```
var twoFactorProviders = await _userManager.GetValidTwoFactorProvidersAsync(user);
```

You will get providers such as "Email", "Phone" and "Authenticator"

Note that for the Email and Phone to be listed, both values have to be present in the AspNetUsers table, and both should be confirmed

Another way is to check if "[GetAuthenticatorKeyAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.iuserauthenticatorkeystore-1.getauthenticatorkeyasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1)" returns null:

```
var authenticatorKey = await _userManager.GetAuthenticatorKeyAsync(user);
```